# function is looped according to setinterval but with different parameters

Tags: javascript, ajax, coldfusion, parameters, setinterval

i have a simple question, there is a function with parameter emp_id that opens up a form for a chat with different attributes, i want it to be refreshed automatically each 10 sec, now it works a bit wrongly, since there is a parameter emp_id that is can be changed, and once i change it, the chat with messages and form are refreshed double time or triple times :) depend on how many times u change the emp_id, i hope i was clear )) anyway here is the javascript function:

```
function load_chat(emp_id) {
        var url = "#request.self#?fuseaction=objects2.popup_list_chatform"
        url = url + "&employee_id=" + emp_id;
        document.getElementById('form_div').style.display = 'block';                            AjaxPageLoad(url,'form_div',1,'Yükleniyor');
        setInterval( function() { 
            load_chat(emp_id); 
        },10000);
}
```

there a list of names, once i click on one of them, this form is opened by this function, but if i click another user, i mean if i change the emp_id, it refreshes, the previous and present form. how do i change it so that it will refresh only the last emp_id, but not all of id's which i've changed

thank you all for the help, i really appreciate it!

Comment: BTW: Its not a good idea to start intervals from intervals recursively...

Comment: @Bergi i know ) that's the problem, it is looped for each of the emp_id i've selected )) not for the last one.

Comment: @venom so is it supposed to stop the previous timer when you change the `emp_id` ?

Comment: @Bergi np, i've rewrited it ))

Comment: @Jack yes, it is exactly what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would nicely encapsulate what you're doing. The timer id (`tid`) is kept inside the closure, so when you call `load_chat` it will stop the interval if there was one running.

Once the new url is set up, it will start the interval timer again.

```
var ChatModule = (function() {
    var tid,
    url;

    function refresh()
    {
        AjaxPageLoad(url, 'form_div', 1, 'Yükleniyor');
    }

    return {
        load_chat: function(emp_id) {
            if (tid) {
                clearInterval(tid);
            }
            // setup url
            url = "#request.self#?fuseaction=objects2.popup_list_chatform"
            url = url + "&employee_id=" + emp_id;
            document.getElementById('form_div').style.display = 'block';
            // load ajax
            refresh();
            // set timer
            tid = setInterval(refresh, 10000);
        }
    }
}());

ChatModule.load_chat(123);
```

Comment: wait a bit i will check this one out soon :)

Comment: as far as i understood by 123 u mean any other emp_id?!

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout` instead. Each time your function is executed, it will set up the next execution (you could also make it conditional):

```
function load_chat(emp_id) {
    ... // do something
    if (condition_still_met)
        setTimeout(function() { 
            load_chat(emp_id); // with same id
        }, 10000);
}
load_chat("x"); // to start
```

Or you will have to use setInterval outside the `load_chat` function. You can clear the interval when necessary.

```
function get_chat_loader(emp_id) {
    return function() {
        ... // do something 
    };
}
var id = setInterval(get_chat_loader("x"), 10000); // start

// then, somewhen later:
clearInterval(id);
```

Comment: can u rewrite it a bit, in a my function way :) i didn't catch up with you ))

Comment: Why rewrite it? What didn't you understand?